# Rotate a sprite along an axis

Tags: sprite-kit, rotation, game-physics

In SpriteKit I need to rotate a sprite along an axis (e.g. the one that passes through the center of the sprite) just like a wheel to be spinned by the user.

I tried to use `applyTorque` function (to apply a force that is only angular and not linear), but I cannot handle the different forces caused by different movements on the screen (longer the touch on the screen, stronger the force to apply).

Can someone help me to understand how to deal with this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "handle the different forces caused by different movements o the screen"?

Comment: sorry, I mean this: starting from the wheel if you press and swipe it must rotate; if the swipe is long means that the user wants to have a great spin, instead if the swipe is short the user wants to have a little spin. I need a way to distinguish this two kind of situations and apply a torque based on this.

Comment: I know how to do this. You just need a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` (or implement something of your own that is similar with touchesMoved and friends) and then check the recognizer object's `.velocity` and apply a torque based on that. I can update my answer if you want but maybe not today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer that spins a ball according to how fast you swipe left / right:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

  let speedLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Speed: 0")
  let wheel      = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)

  var recognizer:  UIPanGestureRecognizer!

  func pan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: view!).x

    // Play with this value until if feels right to you.
    let adjustor = CGFloat(60)

    let speed = velocity / adjustor
    wheel.physicsBody!.angularVelocity = -speed
  }

  // Scene setup:
  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    removeAllChildren()

    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)

    wheel.fillColor = .blue
    wheel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
    wheel.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    let wheelDot = SKSpriteNode(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: 5, height:5))
    wheel.addChild(wheelDot)
    wheelDot.position.y += 20
    wheel.setScale(3)

    speedLabel.setScale(3)
    speedLabel.position.y = (frame.maxY - speedLabel.frame.size.height / 2) - 45

    recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)

    addChild(wheel)
    addChild(speedLabel)
  }

  override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    speedLabel.text = "Speed: \(abs(Int(wheel.physicsBody!.angularVelocity)))"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!! That's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of spinning a wheel clockwise or counterclockwise depending on if you press on left / right side of screen. Hold to increase speed:

```
class GameScene : SKScene {

  enum Direction { case left, right }

  var directionToMove: Direction?

  let wheel = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25)
  let speedLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Speed: 0")

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    // Scene setup:
    anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    removeAllChildren()

    physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)

    wheel.fillColor = .blue
    wheel.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
    wheel.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    let wheelDot = SKSpriteNode(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: 5, height:5))
    wheel.addChild(wheelDot)
    wheelDot.position.y += 20
    wheel.setScale(3)


    speedLabel.setScale(3)
    speedLabel.position.y = (frame.maxY - speedLabel.frame.size.height / 2) - 45

    addChild(wheel)
    addChild(speedLabel)
  }

  // Change this to touchesBegan for iOS:
  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Change this to touches.first!.location(in: self) for iOS.
    let location = event.location(in: self)

    // Determine if touch left or right side:
    if location.x > 0 {
     directionToMove = .right
    }
    else if location.x < 0 {
      directionToMove = .left
    }
  }

  override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
    // Stop applying gas:
    directionToMove = nil
    print("lol")
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // This is how much speed we gain each frame:
    let torque = CGFloat(0.01)

    guard let direction = directionToMove else { return }

    // Apply torque in the proper direction
    switch direction {
    case .left:
      wheel.physicsBody!.applyTorque(torque)
    case .right:
      wheel.physicsBody!.applyTorque(-torque)
    }
  }

  override func didSimulatePhysics() {
    // Speedometer:
    speedLabel.text = "Speed: \(abs(Int(wheel.physicsBody!.angularVelocity)))"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good starting point! Also if in this case, since in iOS the canvas starts from (0,0), the direction left is never called. However, I need a way to handle the different forces applied to the wheel

Comment: set your anchorpoint to 0.5 0.5 sorry i had an sks file @ThugMazzola